# Script working on Mac but not Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell-script

The script executes on a Mac machine and creates the output file, although on an Ubuntu machine it generates error message. Bash shell is used on both instances.:

```
1 - /var
2 - /etc : 
1
: bad variable name: read: word
first_part(1).sh: 6: first_part(1).sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")
```

-

```
echo "To scan through the directories /var and /etc type 1 or 2: "
echo "1 - /var"
echo "2 - /etc : "
read word
case $word in
         1)
                find /var -type d -follow -ls | awk '{print $3, $5, $6, $11}' > var.txt
                echo "Your file containing /var information has been created."
                ;;
         2)
                find /etc -type d -follow -ls | awk '{print $3, $5, $6, $11}' > etc.txt
                echo "Your file containing /etc information has been created."
                ;;
         *)
                echo "Please insert a valid input"
                continue
                ;;

esac
```

Comment: How do you execute the file? `bash filename`?

Comment: `sh filename.sh`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you execute the file by using `sh filename.sh`, then one problem is that, 
on your Ubuntu system, this might not execute `bash` but some other shell. On my Ubuntu 12.04 system `sh` is `/bin/sh` and is soft linked to `/bin/dash` (with a `d`; see ["Dash as /bin/sh"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)).

You should use `bash filename.sh`, or use a shebang line and make the file executable (`chmod +x filename.sh`).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "To scan through the directories /var and /etc type 1 or 2: "
echo "1 - /var"
.
.
```

One thing to check when moving files from Mac to Ubuntu are the newlines of the file (use `od -c file_name`), if there are '\r' characters in the output, but not `\n` you have to convert e.g. using:

`tr '\r' '\n' < file_name > new_file_name`.

Comment: :~/Desktop# bash first_part\(1\).sh 
To scan through the directories /var and /etc type 1 or 2: 
1 - /var
2 - /etc : 
': not a valid identifier read: `word
first_part(1).sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'irst_part(1).sh: line 6: `case $word in

That just executes the file without giving me any option to enter.

Comment: As you can see - your formatted text looks awful in comments!  It's far better to edit your post instead.

Comment: I cannot read that error to well, but the changing error output confirms that you were **not** using bash when using `ubuntu`. Check that you actually use bash on the mac (`sh --version`) and post a new question with the differences in bash execution on the two machines if it does.

Comment: @garethTheRed A new question would be more appropriate, that is different issue from thinking that the OP is using bash, when in fact he isn't

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.3.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`,
`GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)`

Comment: @nicoX I suggest you make a new question, state the versions of bash there and the difference in result on the script you provided, including a properly formatted error message. I think you might have an end-of line issue here. So also give the output from `od -c filename.sh | head -10` in that new question.

Comment: Made a new file of the script, and it works. Couldn't spot any difference though with `vimdiff` and `diff`, even though `diff` said files differ.

Comment: @nicoX use `od -c` on both files, I bet you the end-of-lines differ ( '\n' for the new one probably `\r' for the old one ). If that is so, what editor did you use on the Mac?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Used vim on both, both this file gives same error on the Mac. Might have done edits to it, after transferring it to the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I have updated the answer, so future visitors don't have to wade through this comments. If this solves your problem is there a chance you'll accept this answer?

Comment: a few words on dash vs bash from ubuntu : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

Comment: It's always good when **shebang**'s.

Comment: @Joshpbarron :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another couple of alternatives to:

```
sh filename.sh
```

are

```
source filename.sh
```

and

```
. filename.sh
```

I switch between Ubuntu and OSX several times a day and share my dotfiles and this seems to work for me.

fyi for OSX specific stuff I put it in `.bash_profile` and then that `source`'s `.bashrc` which has stuff which is common to both systems.